# Inheritance from an Interface

Tags: java, interface

I have an interface at the top of my program (`IVehicle`), below this is a class which implements the majority of the inherited methods (`Vehicle`).

Below `Vehicle` is two more classes, `Fueled`, and `Non-Fuelled`.

`Fueled` needs methods to get/set/increment the `fuel` field, `Non-Fulled` doesn't.

My problem is that without putting the methods into the interface, when I try to call them from elsewhere in my program Java won't allow it - I either have to cast (which I don't believe is an option here as I have two separate types of `Vehicle`) or create the method.

Is there anyway to deal with this, other than creating a method in the interface?
If that is the only option, how would I deal with the Inheritance in the `Non-Fuelled` class?

Comment: Please provide some actual code

Comment: I don't understand why you feel that casting isn't an option; maybe posting code, as Dgrin91 suggested, would illustrate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole point of an interface is that it represents a level of abstraction - you're saying "All types that implement this interface support these operations."

It sounds like the operations of "change the fuel field" simply don't belong in that interface, because they're not common to all implementations. Code using the interface can't call those operations, because they may not be supported by the implementation.

You *can* cast, if you really want to:

```
if (vehicle instanceof Fueled) {
    Fueled fueled = (Fueled) vehicle;
    // Perform Fueled-specific operations here
}
```

... but that's *usually* (not always, but usually) a sign that your design has gone astray, and you should really think about it more carefully. It's coupling this code very tightly to `Fueled`.

Or you *could* add the operations to `IVehicle` (which isn't a conventional name for an interface in Java, by the way) and just implement them with no-op methods where they don't make sense. But that's a bit of a design smell. *Sometimes* it may be the cleanest approach, but try to avoid it.

(It's hard to give concrete advise without having the *real* design situation in front of us.)

Answer (score 2):

I think you have a design problem.

You should probably consider making `Fueled` and `NonFueled` interfaces as well, then have them implemented by the `FueledVehicle` and `NonFueledVehicle` concrete classes.

Depending on how deep down this hierarchy you're willing to code, it might be either literally a `FueledVehicle` and a `NonFueledVehicle` classes extending abstract `Vehicle` and each implementing their own interface, or specific models, etc.

As mentioned by others in this thread, it would be easier to help you if you provided some actual code.

Please also note that as a last resort you could always throw `UnsupportedOperationException` in the implemented methods of classes that should not implement, although this would still look like a workaround a bad design in this instance.